# Clipboard to .txt file or similar Python OSX

Tags: python, macos, clipboard

I'm using selenium to click a button in browser which acts to copy text to clipboard. 
Once copied, I need to be able to manipulate the text, preferably by storing the text as an object or by 'pasting' into a .txt file or similar.

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

There are shell commands for accessing the Mac Pasteboard: `pbcopy` and `pbpaste`. You can use them in python with `os.system` or `subprocess`.

[Here's another answer for using shell commands in python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)